# .txt array out from user input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have since updated this code per suggestions for this forum. I am still confused as to how to get my .txt file selection to out print all instances of the name entered. my file in which all my .txt files are contained is named, namesbystate. To access this and all instances of the names entered are where I am getting issues. I am wondering if I replace myFile with namesbystate as a pathway extension or not?

```
package babynamestatesocial;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.*;

public class BabyNameStateSocial {

private Scanner x;

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

// Scanner variable set up to intake user input for state selection and person's name
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Available state files are: \n" +
        "AK " + "AL " + "AR " + "AZ " + "CA " + "CO " + "\n" +
        "CT " + "DC " + "DE " + "FL " + "GA " + "HI " + "\n" +
        "IA " + "ID " + "IL " + "IN " + "KS " + "KY " + "\n" +
        "LA " + "MA " + "MD " + "ME " + "MI " + "MN " + "\n" +
        "MO " + "MS " + "MT " + "NC " + "ND " + "NE " + "\n" +
        "NH " + "NJ " + "NM " + "NV " + "NY " + "OH " + "\n" +
        "OK " + "OR " + "PA " + "RI " + "SC " + "SD " + "\n" +
        "TN " + "TX " + "UT " + "VA " + "VT " + "WA " + "\n" +
        "WI " + "WV " + "WY " + "\n");
System.out.print("Enter a state to read names from: " + "\n");
String filename = scan.nextLine() + ".txt";
System.out.println("Which name would you like to look up?");
String personName = scan.nextLine();

File myFile = new File(filename);

openFile(myFile,personName);

}

private static void openFile(File myFile, String personName){
try {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(myFile);
    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        // nextLine variable now has the line from the file in it that matches the name the person input
        String nextLine = sc.nextLine();
        if (nextLine.contains(personName)) {

        }
    }
} catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.print(e.getMessage());
}
}

}
```

Comment: Please take the time to correctly format your code. Your indents are off. You can use your IDEs auto-formatter or an online formatter.

Comment: What is a "*snippet.xml error*"? Please remember to always post the full error message together with a stack trace and a [mcve] (see [ask]).

Comment: Resources never belong inside a java source folder. Put them in a separate `res` folder or something. But not inside `src` nor inside any java package.

Comment: If you want to keep your program alive and do multiple rounds, you need some kind of loop. For example a `while (keepRunning) { ... }` loop with a boolean `keepRunning` which starts at `true` and may be modified by user input to `false` for termination.

Comment: Your `main` method asks the user for a state and a name to look up, and then just stops.  If you want any more than that to happen, you need to write some additional code inside of `main` to make it happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this will get you to where you want to be. I do not have the format of your state text files so I couldn't write the full program for you

(Edit - I just changed the code slightly. Instead of sc.next(), I should have written sc.nextLine(). The following program runs successfully with that edit):

```
package babynamestatesocial;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.*;

public class BabyNameStateSocial {



private Scanner x;

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {


    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Available state files are: \n" +
            "AK " + "AL " + "AR " + "AZ " + "CA " + "CO " + "\n" +
            "CT " + "DC " + "DE " + "FL " + "GA " + "HI " + "\n" +
            "IA " + "ID " + "IL " + "IN " + "KS " + "KY " + "\n" +
            "LA " + "MA " + "MD " + "ME " + "MI " + "MN " + "\n" +
            "MO " + "MS " + "MT " + "NC " + "ND " + "NE " + "\n" +
            "NH " + "NJ " + "NM " + "NV " + "NY " + "OH " + "\n" +
            "OK " + "OR " + "PA " + "RI " + "SC " + "SD " + "\n" +
            "TN " + "TX " + "UT " + "VA " + "VT " + "WA " + "\n" +
            "WI " + "WV " + "WY " + "\n");
    System.out.print("Enter a state to read names from: " + "\n");
    String filename = scan.nextLine() + ".txt";
    System.out.println("Which name would you like to look up?");
    String personName = scan.nextLine();

    File myFile = new File(filename);

    openFile(myFile,personName);

}

private static void openFile(File myFile, String personName){
    try {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(myFile);
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            String nextLine = sc.nextLine();
            if (nextLine.contains(personName)) {
                //nextLine variable now has the line from the file in it that matches the name the person input so you need to parse that line and do something with it
            }
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.print(e.getMessage());
    }
}

}
```

Comment: This seems to work I will just need to figure out how to include my files now. Thank you so much!

Comment: My files are in a folder named "namesbystate" I have tried replacing the code to private static void openFile(File namesbystate) and it still seems to build succelsfully but not print out all the files under a specific name. I am confused as to where exactly the file name should be placed to pull from specific .txt files. I.E; SC.TXT, NC.TXT, etc. and suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The file path is relative to your executable (this program). So just add the path in front of the filename kind of like this (if your directory was parallel to the executable) :  String myPath = "../namesbystate/"; String filename = myPath + scan.nextLine() + ".txt";